# How to not display XMLNAMESPACES alias

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, soap, namespaces

I understand the main purpose of `XMLNAMESPACES` clause is to declare the namespace and use it further.

I have the following code

```
DECLARE @XMLFINAL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @XMLFINAL=''
DECLARE @NUMBER NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @XML VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE Records CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

SELECT TOP 1 GID FROM PurchasesDocumentsLines

OPEN Records
FETCH NEXT FROM Records INTO @NUMBER
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
SET @XML=''    


;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('OrderedProductSection' as q17)

SELECT @XML= (

SELECT 
ProductCode as 'q17:ProductCode', OrderedQuantity 'q17:OrderedQuantity'

FROM PurchasesDocumentsLines WHERE GID=@NUMBER
FOR
XML RAW('q17:OrderedProductSection'), ELEMENTS
)
```

That generate the following output

```
<q17:OrderedProducts xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">
<q17:OrderedProductSection xmlns:q17="OrderedProductSection">
<q17:ProductCode>19A0010000</q17:ProductCode>
<q17:OrderedQuantity>2</q17:OrderedQuantity>
</q17:OrderedProductSection>
<q17:OrderedProductSection xmlns:q17="OrderedProductSection">
<q17:ProductCode>1G5Y010000</q17:ProductCode>
<q17:OrderedQuantity>3</q17:OrderedQuantity>
</q17:OrderedProductSection>
<q17:OrderedProductSection xmlns:q17="OrderedProductSection">
<q17:ProductCode>1G5Y020000</q17:ProductCode>
<q17:OrderedQuantity>4</q17:OrderedQuantity>
</q17:OrderedProductSection>
<q17:OrderedProductSection xmlns:q17="OrderedProductSection">
<q17:ProductCode>1G5Y030000</q17:ProductCode>
<q17:OrderedQuantity>5</q17:OrderedQuantity>
</q17:OrderedProductSection>
<q17:OrderedProductSection xmlns:q17="OrderedProductSection">
<q17:ProductCode>1G5Y040000</q17:ProductCode>
<q17:OrderedQuantity>6</q17:OrderedQuantity>
</q17:OrderedProductSection>
</q17:OrderedProducts>
```

And now, the dumb question, hoping to find a solution: Is there any way that for `<q17:OrderedProductSection xmlns:q17="OrderedProductSection">` tag, to not display the `xmlns:q17="OrderedProductSection"`? Because, having an empty URI is not allowed. Thanks

**LE**

Achieve it with `REPLACE` function.

**Edit**

```
<q17:OrderedProducts xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">
    <q17:ProductCode>19A0010000</q17:ProductCode>
    <q17:OrderedQuantity>2</q17:OrderedQuantity>
    <q17:ProductCode>1G5Y010000</q17:ProductCode>
    <q17:OrderedQuantity>3</q17:OrderedQuantity>
</q17:OrderedProducts>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Never do this in a `CURSOR`!** They are bad and evil, coming directly of the hell of procedural thinking and were invented by the devil of spaghetti code...

Each separate call to `FOR XML` will introduce the namespace. That's by design!

This can be done much faster, cleaner and better with a set based approach:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(ProductCode VARCHAR(100),OrderedQuantity INT);
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
 ('19A0010000',2)
,('1G5Y010000',3);

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects' AS q17)
SELECT ProductCode AS [q17:ProductCode]
      ,OrderedQuantity AS [q17:OrderedQuantity]
FROM @table AS t
FOR XML PATH('q17:OrderedProductSection'),ROOT('q17:OrderedProducts');
```

Will return this

```
<q17:OrderedProducts xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">
  <q17:OrderedProductSection>
    <q17:ProductCode>19A0010000</q17:ProductCode>
    <q17:OrderedQuantity>2</q17:OrderedQuantity>
  </q17:OrderedProductSection>
  <q17:OrderedProductSection>
    <q17:ProductCode>1G5Y010000</q17:ProductCode>
    <q17:OrderedQuantity>3</q17:OrderedQuantity>
  </q17:OrderedProductSection>
</q17:OrderedProducts>
```

Comment: is there any way to avoid the `root` and make the code to look like in my edit? Thanks

Comment: @cdrrrrr Where are the `<OrderedProductSection>`?

Comment: @cdrrrrr If you really need it as in your edit, it's easy (but I would not suggest this structure!). Just replace the last line of code to `FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('q17:OrderedProducts');`. The empty `PATH('')` will return with no row-wrapping node

Comment: Also, can you please tell me why do you not suggest this structure? What's the disadvantages of using it? Thanks

Comment: I have one more challenge. Is there any way that for each `<ProductCode>` and `<Quantity>' to have a different XML file? In my case/example, I should have two XML generated files since are two lines with product and their quantity.

Comment: @cdrrrrr This is a bad structure, because you have to rely on the alternating existance of code and quantity. One missing element will break your structure. Best was something like this: `<Product code="1G5Y010000" Qty="12"/>`. The attribute centered approach is a very tense binding between an element and its details. Attributes are unique by definition. If you stick with your approach, I'd keep the *row-wrapping* node `<OrderedProductSection>`. It helps you reading this...

Comment: @cdrrrrr, Writing many different files to disc is not just *one more challenge*... Please avoid chameleon questions... StackOverflow is not only a site to get help, but also a huge archive of answered questions. Therefore the principle: One issue - one question. The initial question was about *How to place the namespaces*, which seems to be solved. If so, please upvote and accept my answer by clicking the check below the vote counter to close this question and mark it as solved. Than start a new question for the new problem.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks.